# Google sheets. Compare the value in column on the 1st sheet with 2 others and then pull cells to y the right of matching value in the other sheets

Tags: formulas, google-sheets

I have one workbook,  3 sheets. Ultimately I'd like information from sheet 2 and 3 joined with corresponding information on the 1st sheet.

The 1st column has an ID number on each page. How can I make it so that the sheet takes the id from the 1st sheet, finds it on the 2 other sheets and copies the cells to the right on the same row to where I want them on the 1st sheet.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `vlookup()`. Put `ID Number` in cell `A1` of all the three sheets. Then clear columns `Sheet1!D1:G` and put this formula in cell `D1`:

```
=arrayformula( iferror( vlookup(A1:A, Sheet2!A1:C, { 2, 3 }, false) ) )
```

...and this formula in cell `F1`:

```
=arrayformula( iferror( vlookup(A1:A, Sheet3!A1:C, { 2, 3 }, false) ) )
```

See the [vlookup()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093318)  help page.